# Optimal placement of Cassandra saved_caches_directory?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've read advice indicating it's best to set up Cassandra's `data_file_directories` and `commitlog_directory` on different devices (seems sensible.) What the sample `cassandra.yaml`'s comments actually say: "when running on magnetic HDD, this should be a separate spindle than the data directories."

I'm wondering if there's any particular guidance with respect to the `saved_caches_directory`.  OK to keep it on the same device/filesystem as the `data_file_directories`?  Better to point elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Visit https://github.com/dell-oss/Doradus/wiki/Cassandra-Configuration-Files

there is the explanation:

> saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
>
> Set this option to a valid folder name where Cassandra will save key and row caches that it builds. It can be the same disk as the commit log or where software is installed, but it shouldn’t be one of the SSTable disks. The size of disk space for caches depend on cache option settings.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't read any specific recommendations for that.  The amount of data written for saved caches is probably quite small compared to the data files and commitlog, so it probably doesn't make much difference where you set it.

I think it should be fine to set it to the same volume as the data.

If you have a dedicated drive for the commitlog, then I wouldn't save the caches to that drive to avoid moving the write head.  The idea of having a dedicated drive for the commitlog is that the write head will always be positioned for writing commitlog data.